# Rails JQuery Timepicker : "No method slider"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm try to use the Timepicker addon to the JQuery Datepicker widget.
When I call 
`$(function (){
        $('#scan_time').datetimepicker();
});` and click on the text field I get the following error in my Chrome console

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'slider'

I am loading all the files in my Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

and I have the time picker addon.js in my Javascripts in my javascripts directory

Comment: Do you have the jQuery UI Slider plugin in your jQuery UI? Make sure you include it when you build your jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: I'm loading the JQuery through the gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12' gem. Does that include it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be absolutely sure your js files are all being loaded. Search for the contents in application.js after the page is loaded...

Comment: The jquery-ui.js is included in the rendered HTML page in the head. I searched and the jQuery UI Slider 1.8.16 is in the source